# Ableton Live: APC40 toggle Midi map states?

Tags: midi, ableton-live

There are a lot of mappings I want to use, but I don't want to override the default APC40 setup.

I'm curious how you can manage different Midi maps using Ableton Live or external software.

Thanks

Comment: Can you send a MIDI message to change the MIDI mapping?

Comment: Probably, but I'm pretty new to the DAW and using the controller as well